# Fiware Quantum Leap Date Query

Tags: sql, fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus, cratedb

I am currently using Quantum Leap/CrateDB to persist time series data through the Orion Context Broker.

After setting up the notification on Orion I can query data.

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:8668/v2/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:Pmr_obs:001/attrs/slotStatus?limit=3" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Fiware-Service: atos" -H "Fiware-ServicePath: /mtp"
```

Response

```
{
  "attrName": "slotStatus",
  "entityId": "urn:ngsi-ld:Pmr_obs:001",
  "index": [
    "2019-07-28T19:00:00.000+00:00",
    "2019-07-29T07:00:00.000+00:00",
    "2019-07-29T10:00:00.000+00:00"
  ],
  "values": [
    0,
    1,
    0
  ]
}
```

But when I try to query data over a specific period (between two dates), the server returns all the indices and the values and not for the period I select.

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:8668/v2/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:Pmr_obs:001/attrs/slotStatus?dateFrom=2020-12-01T00:00:00.000Z&dateTo=2020-12-31T23:59:59.999Z" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Fiware-Service: atos" -H "Fiware-ServicePath: /mtp"
```

```
Response (all the values from 2019 to end of 2020)
```

What is strange is that if I use an aggregate method it filters the data correctly using the specific date period.

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:8668/v2/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:Pmr_obs:001/attrs/slotStatus?aggrMethod=count&dateFrom=2020-12-01&dateTo=2020-12-31" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Fiware-Service: atos" -H "Fiware-ServicePath: /mtp"
```

Response

```
{
  "attrName": "slotStatus",
  "entityId": "urn:ngsi-ld:Pmr_obs:001",
  "index": [],
  "values": [
    1101
  ]
}
```

What should I do to only query data from a specific period without an aggregate method?

Thanks in advance.

quantumleap:0.8
crate:4.1.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We investigated the [issue](https://github.com/orchestracities/ngsi-timeseries-api/issues/642#issuecomment-1133215934).

the query used contains `dateFrom` and `dateTo` but as per quantumleap's API specification it should be `fromDate` and `toDate` (which should work fine).